# Code Igniter - Can't detect my current latitude/longitude location in google maps V3 API

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I want to display my current latitude/longitude. This is my source code of controller. I load google maps V3 API library for CI.
The problem is my current latitude / longitude is displayed wrong value **when I echo '$center_lat'(my latitude) and '$center_long' (my longitude)**. **Can you help me to find the real latitude and longitude of my current location ????**

```
function GetMarkers()
        {

            $this->load->library('googlemaps');
            $config = array();
            $config['center'] = 'auto';
            $config['onboundschanged'] = 'if (!centreGot) 
                                        {
                                            var mapCentre = map.getCenter();
                                            marker_0.setOptions({
                                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapCentre.lat(), mapCentre.lng()) 
                                            });
                                        }
                                        centreGot = true;';
            $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
            $marker = array();
            $marker['position'] = $config['center'];
            $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Current Position !';
            $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|6FBA33|000000';
            $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
            $center_lat = $this->googlemaps->markersInfo['marker_0']['latitude'];
            $center_long = $this->googlemaps->markersInfo['marker_0']['longitude'];

            echo $center_lat . " <----> " . $center_long;
        }
```

Comment: How are you getting your current location?  What is it?  What should it be?

Comment: I use googlemaps library. This is how i get my current location --> $config['center'] = 'auto'. And I get wrong value of my latitude/longitude location.

Comment: That isn't part of the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  Is it a codeigniter thing?

Comment: Yes, that's why I use it. Here's the link : http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndikaK - Thanks for using my library. Firstly, in your question you should really link to any libraries/plugins being used so people can help more. Prior to you mentioning it in the comments, how was anyone to know that you were using this particular library?

In response to your question, the geocoding is actually done in JavaScript by the Google Maps API, and therefore this information won't be available in PHP as you are trying to do.

If you do need the value in PHP for whatever reason, an AJAX request will be the only way to go I'm afraid.

Hope that points you in right direction.

Comment: Thanks for creating google maps library. It helps me. Yes, you're right, now I use javascript for knowing my current location